# Setting UIImageView image from ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

iPhone n00b here, although I do have an app in the store.

I have two simple ViewControllers, taken directly from the Utility Application template in xCode. I have two `UIImageViews`, one on each ViewController in a storyboard. I have the outlets hooked up correctly (as far as I know) because I can set the image of the *first* ViewController fine with

`[self.imageView setImage:@"test.png"]`

When I try to do essentially the same thing in my `FlipsideViewController`, nothing happens.

```
- (void)selectImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    NSLog(@"%@", img);
    self.editImageView.image = img;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.editImageView.image);
}
```

This code, gives the correct result after logging the first `NSLog` statement, but the second line does not have the desired effect, and the third line yields `(null)`.

EDIT: the coed is updated to reflect the fact that I want to display "img" rather than another image initialized using `imageNamed`, that was simply a test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're passing a `UIImage` to your method, why are you then setting the `imageView` via the `imageNamed:` function?

If you're passing the correct `UIImage` then you should just do the following.

```
- (void)selectImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    NSLog(@"%@", img); // This is the UIImage being passed.
    [self.editImageView setImage:img];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.editImageView.image);
}
```

From what I can see that is all that is needed. If this is wrong, please update your question so I can answer accordingly.

**Edited due to comments**

So, from the comments I have gathered what the issue is.

You're saying that in `-(void)viewDidLoad` you can set the image, that is easy, with the `[UIImage imageNamed:]` method. That's fine, but you want to do it in a separate method which is causing the issue.

What I'd suggest is doing the following, for testing sakes.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

      UIImage *imageYouWantToPass = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
      [self selectImage:imageYouWantToPass];

 }
```

Make sure that the method `selectImage:` is added to your `.h` file so that you don't get any warnings. I think this is what the answer is, but if this still doesn't resolve your question please provide more information.

Comment: Yes, and it had no effect. The image _will_ however load if I put the code `[editImageView setImage:[UIImage imagenamed:@"test.png"]];` into the FlipsideViewController's `- (void)viewDidLoad` method. This presents another problem though, as I cannot access the img property of the MainViewController from the viewDidLoad method of the FlipsideViewController. Bleh!

Comment: I ended up solving the issue by the fact that `- (void)wiewDidLoad` is called every time I switch views. The code in your answer works, and all I had to do was make my MainViewController set a UIImage variable (editImage) local to the FlipsideViewController whenever an image is selected from the MainViewController. When one switches views, I call `[editImageView setImage:editImage]` and the FlipsideViewController sets the image of the editImageView in the viewDidLoad method based on what editImage was set to. Thanks for your persistance!

Answer (score 1):

`[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imagenamed:@"test.png"]]`

There u are missing..

And in second case. It seems that you have connected `imageView` to `.xib` but not the property.Try using it without self. Or declare `IBOutlet` in property

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `editImageView` is initialized properly or not. First NSLog works proper means you have proper image and second NSLog does not work mean there might be a problem with `editImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

As you're passing a `UIImage` to your method(`selectImage:`) Then No need to set the `imageView (UIImageView)` via the `imageNamed:` method.
Because you have `UIImage` in the `img` instance, you can just set the `image` from `img` within the function.

If you're passing the correct `UIImage` then you should just do the following.

```
- (void)selectImage:(UIImage *)img
{   
     NSLog(@"%@", img); // here you have Image in img, so just set Image From this img.

     [self.editImageView setImage:img];
     NSLog(@"%@", self.editImageView.image);
}
```

I hope it clears everything...!!!!

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not with displaying the wrong image, but displaying an image at all. I did not make that clear, and have changed my question to reflect that.

Comment: @stevesullivan NP,you need to pass the `Image` to that method(`selectImage`) when ever you call that method As `[self selectImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];`

Comment: Yes, I realize this, and the fact that the first NSLog statement prints correctly confirms this. I know that img is being passed correctly. The trouble is that [self.editImageView setImage:img]; doesnt seem to have any effect, i.e. NSLog(@"%@", self.editImageView.image); returns (null).

Comment: @stevesullivan As you are saying that `img` contains  proper`image`you must check ,have you created the object of `editImageView(UIImageView)`.
i am pretty Sure if everything going fine(according you), then error may be in this `UIImageView`.SO please Check this `editImageView`.

Comment: I believe everything was initialized correctly, but the issue stemmed from the fact that the image could not be set while loading the view. I did get everything working based on Sebastien Peek's answer and a little creativity on my part. Thanks for your responses.